# What is reason to inject Fragment or Activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am beggining with Dagger 2 on Android and I would like to know what is the reason to inject Fragment or Activity to Application. I thought that dependency injection is about passing parameters to constructor. So in Android development one passes functionality. (RestClient, SharedPrefs etc.), but injecting Fragment doesnt make sense from this point of view.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you inject your Fragment or Activity into your Application that's a great way to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are re-usable. There is some cases that you might want to use same fragment object again and again.

For example, you have a DialogFragment which shows a general error. Instead of creating new fragment object which has same functionality for per errors, you can re attach it.

So injection is good choice to keep that instance.

Comment: So it is not general usage for every fragment in your app ?

Comment: yep its not general. Just for some cases